# Put x-editable source in html instead of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

Per https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html, a select menu is configured as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="status" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select status"></a>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#status').editable({
        value: 2,    
        source: [
              {value: 1, text: 'Active'},
              {value: 2, text: 'Blocked'},
              {value: 3, text: 'Deleted'}
           ]
    });
});
</script>
```

I would like the source to be stored in the page's HTML instead of JavaScript.  What is the "proper" way of doing so?

Comment: Have you tried `data-value="2" data-source='[{value: 1, text: "text1"}, {value 2, text: "text2"}, ...]'` ? See the docs under `select2`

Comment: @JuanMendes  Perfect!  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their docs

> Options can be defined via javascript $().editable({...}) or via data-* html attributes.

You can just pass them JSON encoded as `data-attributes`

```
<a href="#" id="status" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-url="/post"
            data-title="Select status" data-value="2"
            data-source='[{value: 1, text: "text1"}, {value 2, text: "text2"}, ...]'> </a>
```

Comment: Glad it was you who posted an answer.  Would have hated to select another after the solution came from you comment.  Thanks!

Comment: Everythin is greate but The problem is that you can't set a selected option with this aproche. Or point otherwais

Comment: Oh sorry found it. Works now. there is a value already defined in a datasource